# Classic JS Prime Number

Tags: javascript, primes

This may be a silly post, but I can't figure out why my code doesn't work properly. For the record I already wrote different code that works, but I still don't understand why this one doesn't.

Why does the second `if` statement always pass as true?

https://jsfiddle.net/vhdh5x3d/2/

```
/* This code doesn't work... */
var testNumber = prompt("Please enter a number you'd like to test");

for (var i = 2; i < testNumber; i++) {
    if (testNumber % i == 0) {
    document.getElementById("test-results").innerHTML = "Your number, " + testNumber + ", is not a prime number.";
  }
  if ((testNumber - 1) == i && testNumber % i != 0 ) {
    document.getElementById("test-results").innerHTML = "Congratulations! Your number, " + testNumber + ", is a prime number!";
  }
}
```

Comment: Mathematically `x % x-1` is always non-zero when `x > 2`. What is the condition supposed to test for?

Comment: youre overriding the result in each for loop?

Comment: Your loop issue is simple. The first if statement may prove true many times, but you'll always hit the second. So eventually the conditions are met as `i` increases. You need a break in your first if statement. also, there are far better ways to get prime numbers

Comment: @JJJ The second `if` is supposed to ensure `i` reached `testNumber - 1` and still failed to divide evenly. That way it the HTML would verify testNumber as prime.

Comment: You would need to test that *every* iteration failed to divide evenly – testing just one number isn't enough. Also, because nothing breaks the loop, `i` will *always* reach that number.

Comment: @JJJ Right, that's why I put the second `if` statement after the first. I figured since both `if` statements can't be true for the same `i` value, the html would only change once.

Comment: It's a loop... they can't be true at the same time during *one iteration*, but the conditions are checked `testNumber` times, so there's no guarantee that the HTML changes only once.

Comment: Just FYI, [Simple method for finding prime numbers](https://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/5pfL4b0p/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to assume that, given a positive integer `testNumber` and another positive integer `i`, then if `((testNumber - 1) == i) && ((testNumber % i) != 0)` that means that `testNumber` is prime.

That assumption is wrong. Consider for example the case `testNumber = 8` and `i = 7`. The above condition holds, however 8 is not a prime number.

Answer (score 0):

The second `if` is not always true, it is only in the last iteration of the `for` loop, so what you see in your html is the prime found message.

You should do something like this:

```
var testNumber = prompt("Please enter a number you'd like to test");
var prime = true;
for (var i = 2; i < testNumber; i++) {
    if (testNumber % i == 0) {
      prime = false;

  }
}

if (prime == true) 
  document.getElementById("test-results").innerHTML = "Congratulations! Your number, " + testNumber + ", is a prime number!";
else
  document.getElementById("test-results").innerHTML = "Your number, " + testNumber + ", is not a prime number.";
```

This is a trivial algorithm that test if a number is or not a prime number. You can find a lot of different algorithms for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Second If statement will not be true always. It will go into your second if statement only during the last iteration and set the html. 
It will always necessary to return the value once your condition is met which you are not doing in your code.

Below code will work:

```
var testNumber = prompt("Please enter a number you'd like to test");

for (var i = 2; i < testNumber; i++) {
    if (testNumber % i == 0) {
    document.getElementById("test-results").innerHTML = "Your number, " + testNumber + ", is not a prime number.";
return;
  }
  if ((testNumber - 1) == i && testNumber % i != 0 ) {
    document.getElementById("test-results").innerHTML = "Congratulations! Your number, " + testNumber + ", is a prime number!";
return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var testNumber = prompt("Please enter a number you'd like to test");
for (var i = 2; i < testNumber; i++) {
  if (testNumber % i == 0) {      
     break;//already found a working number, so stop
  }
}
//if last iteration reached without breaking its a prime
document.getElementById("test-results").innerHTML = "Your number, " + testNumber + ", is "+(testNumber==i?"a":"not a")+" prime number.";
```

http://jsbin.com/qabivasiyu/edit?console

As the comments already pointed out, the second if shouldnt be in the for loop, and the first if should break the loop. Ive also simplified your code a bit...